# Is there any chart library that can be reused for both react for web and react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, data-visualization

If not, then is there any chart (data drawing) library that most components can be reused on both, or at least is compatible enough for react[web] and react-native[mobile] to make the work easier and faster?

Comment: Probably [Highchart](https://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure about `Highchart`. They've published package `highcharts-react-native` but with Deprecation disclaimer. Also it's not free for commercial use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Victory](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory) is a charting library that supports different patterns in modular forms and ready to use components for both React and React Native applications. The React Native variant is also known as Victory Native.

Comment: thanks! I'll check that out

Comment: This library seems compatible for web and mobile, also I haven't found any other alternative